# The document cannot be opened because there is an invalid part with an unexpected content type

Tags: c#, asp.net, powerpoint, openxml-sdk, powerpoint-automation

I am getting a error while opening using a **presentation (PPTX files)** creation code.
Code i am using is given below:

```
  public static void UpdatePPT()
    {
        const string presentationmlNamespace = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main";
        const string drawingmlNamespace = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main";

        string fileName = Server.MapPath("~/PPT1.pptx");  //path of pptx file


        using (PresentationDocument pptPackage = PresentationDocument.Open(fileName, true))
        {


        } // Using pptPackage
}
```

and the error i am getting is:

```
"The document cannot be opened because there is an invalid part with an unexpected content type. 
[Part Uri=/ppt/printerSettings/printerSettings1.bin], 
[Content Type=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.printerSettings], 
[Expected Content Type=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.printerSettings]."
```

error occurs at `using (PresentationDocument pptPackage = PresentationDocument.Open(fileName, true))`

Code works fine for many PPTX files. But it is throwing this error on some files. 
I am not able to find any solution. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Me too stucked on this problem

Comment: I think the file which you are trying to open is not valid Open XML PresentationDocument. Please see the erroneous file whether it is created using PowerPoint 2011 or PowerPoint 2010. May be it might provide you some clue to your problem.

Comment: @DeepakBhatia i can open these file in MS PowerPoint 2013,2010 with no issues.

Comment: DeepSharma, I really think you should mark @YvesR answer as the one. He as fixed it programatically !!! I loved his approach...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have solved my problem. The PPTX i got was developed in mac os. So what i did is i just `opened a working pptx file`. And copied all the `contents of not working pptx into working pptx` and saved it by the name of not working pptx.

Answer (score 5):

Old post, but I ran in to the same problem. I solved it programatically.
Means:

My code runs `using (var document = PresentationDocument.Open(fileName, true))`
If this run into a exception I have a document like described. Then I call `FixPowerpoint()` method and do the other stuff after again.

Here is the method to share (`using System.IO.Packaging`):

```
private static void FixPowerpoint(string fileName)
{
  //Opening the package associated with file
  using (Package wdPackage = Package.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
  {
    //Uri of the printer settings part
    var binPartUri = new Uri("/ppt/printerSettings/printerSettings1.bin", UriKind.Relative);
    if (wdPackage.PartExists(binPartUri))
    {
      //Uri of the presentation part which contains the relationship
      var presPartUri = new Uri("/ppt/presentation.xml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
      var presPart = wdPackage.GetPart(presPartUri);
      //Getting the relationship from the URI
      var presentationPartRels =
          presPart.GetRelationships().Where(a => a.RelationshipType.Equals("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/printerSettings",
              StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).SingleOrDefault();
      if (presentationPartRels != null)
      {
        //Delete the relationship
        presPart.DeleteRelationship(presentationPartRels.Id);
      }

      //Delete the part
      wdPackage.DeletePart(binPartUri);
    }
    wdPackage.Close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! This issue is troubling me for the past few months but I never actually got my hands on solving it. Your solution works.